# Why is my authenticated user returning null even though the user is logged in on the frontend?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, debugging, laravel-passport

I'm trying to verify the currently logged in user in order to store the filename that's being uploaded associated with the currently logged in user into my db.  However, when testing my endpoint via Postman - `dd(auth()->user());` returns `null`.

In my logs I'm getting this error:  `local.ERROR: Call to a member function photos()` which means `auth()->user()` is the problem but I just can't see how.  I've tried too many ways to list here in terms of trying to rectify this problem.

What am I doing wrong?

I'll list some things I've tried:

in the `if()` condition inside FileUploadController - `if(auth()->user())`, `if(Auth::guard(api)->check())`, `if(Auth::check())`.

I have two completely separate code bases: React.js on the frontend and Laravel on the backend

Here's `FileUploadController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {
    public function uploadTest(Request $request) {
        dd(auth()->user());

        if(auth()->user()) {
            auth()->user()->photos()->create([
                'file_path' => $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalExtension()
            ]);
            return response()->json($request->user());
        }
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

Here's my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function photos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
    }
}
```

Here's my Photo model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Here's code for logging in the user inside my AuthController:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    $request->session()->put("user", $user);
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString(),
        $user
    ]);
}
```

Here's the front end of how on submit:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hereee submitHandler()");

    let access_token = Cookies.get("access_token").slice(13, -8);

    const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }

    console.log(this.state.file_path);

    if(this.state.auth) {
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame', this.state.file_path, {headers})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sending the session cookie or Authorization header with your Postman request?

Comment: @fubar yeah I am.  Check my post, I updated it to include my front end.

Comment: Yeah, so you're sending it from React, but are you sending it in Postman?

Comment: @fubar yeah I'm sending it in Postman just like that

Comment: It looks like you're using the standard Auth driver, which would set a PHP session cookie, rather than use a bearer token. If you delete the PHPSESSID cookie from your browser, does your React app still manage to authenticate using the bearer token alone?